# Rails: Passing ActiveRecord Relation object to params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this sample code under the `index` action in my controller:

```
@obj = UserSource.select('user.source_categories.code as category_code,
                      user.source_categories.name as category_name, 
                      count(*)')
             .merge(@sourced_user)
             .joins(:table_1, :table_2)
             .group(1, 2)
             .reorder(count: :desc)
```

In the `index` view everything works as expected. The data stored in `@obj` is showed correctly.

I would like to have:

```
link_to 'category_code', some_path, remote: true
```

Which would direct me to another action of the same controller via an AJAX call. I would like to pass in the `@obj`, which is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object, as one of the params.

I need `@obj` to further process data once in the other action, and if possible the `@obj` needs to be maintained as `ActiveRecord::Relation` object type.

Is it possible to pass `ActiveRecord::Relation` object from one action to another action?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a Ruby object (such as `ActiveRecord::Relation`) over a web request without serializing it. And you probably don't actually want to do that either as it would make a *much* larger than necessary request.

You likely want to send just the information needed to reconstruct the query (any WHERE conditions, for example, that went into `@sourced_user`, or simply define the query as a helper function that both controller actions can call.

If the query becomes more dynamic and complex, look into gems such as [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) that define some easy conventions for passing query params across web requests.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for the reply. The reason why I was thinking of passing @obj as one of the params to the next controller action is because I would like to avoid re-constructing the query as it would have impact on performance, in my opinion. My intention was to do something like @obj.where( some_condition ) depending on which link_to the user selects. But again, I welcome any suggestion/opinions on this matter. Thanks again :)